# Cargar imágenes desde mysql en php con librería fileuploader

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando cargar las imágenes relacionadas con id del producto, pero no se como hacerlo con la librería https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/

He probado añadir el `$appendedFiles`, pero me carga todas las imágenes que están en la carpeta **images**

Este es mi código

```
$id_product = id_product($_GET['id']);

if(empty($id_product)){
    header('Location: home.php');
    }

$product = get_product_per_id($connect, $id_product);

    if (!$product){
    header('Location: ' . SITE_URL . '/controller/home.php');
}

$product = $product['0'];

}           

function galeria($connect){

if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$sentence = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM galeria WHERE product_id = ?');
$sentence->execute([$id]);
return $sentence->fetchAll();

}}


                // create an empty array
                // we will add to this array the files from directory below
                // here you can also add files from MySQL database
                $galeria = galeria($connect);

                $appendedFiles = array($galeria);

                // scan uploads directory
                $uploadsFiles = array_diff(scandir('../images/'), array('.', '..'));

                // add files to our array with
                // made to use the correct structure of a file
                foreach($uploadsFiles as $file) {
                    // skip if directory
                    if(is_dir($file))
                        continue;

                    // add file to our array
                    // !important please follow the structure below
                    $appendedFiles[] = array(
                        "name" => $file,
                        "type" => FileUploader::mime_content_type('../images/' . $file),
                        "size" => filesize('../images/' . $file),
                        "file" => '../images/' . $file,
                        "data" => array(
                            "url" => 'http://localhost/fileuploader/examples/appended-files/uploads/' . $file
                        )
                    );
                }

                // convert our array into json string
                $appendedFiles = json_encode($appendedFiles);
```

El `input` de las imágenes

```
<input type="file" name="files" data-fileuploader-files='<?php echo $appendedFiles;?>'>
```

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme ?!

Comment: Lo siento @anonfidusa. Si no respondemos es porque, probablemente, nadie usa esa biblioteca de funciones. Quizá con un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable (MCVE)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) más sencillo me atrevería a ayudarte aunque no lo haya usado, pero te falta muchísimo código para poder reproducir tu problema en mi equipo y así poder ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @OscarGarcia , solo necesito saber como hacer un select para ponerlo en $appendedFiles = array($galeria);

Comment: No puedo adjuntarlo aqui porque es complicado poner todo el codigo, si quires te puedo pasar el archivo, es un backend muy simple, me funciona todo, puedo subir las imagenes pero no puedo verlas cuando estoy dentro de la ficha del producto.

Comment: Puedes usar un gist: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: **[Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59113/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-anonfidusa).**

Comment: @OscarGarcia !!

Comment: La librería fileuploader es de pago... Has pensado en usar otras librerias?¿
Igual así te podríamos ayudar

Comment: Hola @CarlosGª-muñoz, es de pago solo cuando necesitas soporte, pero es gratis, bueno si conoces otra mejor comentalo, gracias

Comment: Bueno, eso no es del todo cierto.. "A regular licence is required if you are using this plugin in more than one of your projects (including sites for your customers). A commercial licence code is required by including this plugin in commercial applications (including sites, themes and apps you plan to sell). Sharing the source code or selling it particullary is not allowed. 

If you want to try the Fileuploader or you are planning to use this plugin only in ONE (for the next using you will need to pay for a regular lincese) personal and non-commer...."

Comment: Encontre este http://www.dropzonejs.com

Comment: el problema que tengo es a la hora de mostrar las imagenes subidas por id

Comment: ¿? Esta libreria es para SUBIR archivos al servidor de forma "bonita y grafica", para mostrar imagenes no te hace falta libreria

Comment: me refiero a que cuando quiero editar las imagenes de la ficha de un producto necesito mostrar las imagenes relacionadas con dicho producto via id , en la web de la libreria lo explican pero me muestra todas las imagenes de todos los productos ! :/